# Rate of iteration convergence

Tags: fixed-point-iteration

For the iteration

$$x_{n+1}=f(x_n)\equiv \sin(x_n) \text{ with initial value } x_0=1,$$

I know it converges since $x_{n+1}\le x_n$ for all $n$ and the limit is zero, so the iteration converges to zero, but how do I know the **rate** of convergence? Also, what are the effects of rounding errors?

Comment: @par Actually, $x_{n+1} \leq x_n$ and the sequence being bounded *is* a sufficient condition for convergence. Moreover, any limit must be a fixed point of $\sin$, and there is only one of those.

Comment: I would say the rate's not very good, since the derivative of $\sin$ around zero is close to $1$, so we do not have any contraction phenomenon which could make the convergence geometric, for example.

Comment: @par No, it does imply the limit is zero. For a sequence of iterates of a continuous function, any limit is a fixed point.

Comment: Removing myself from this thread as I am on an error-making streak.

Comment: @Ian $x_{n+1}\le x_n$ must have a lower bound for it to converge.

Comment: @SimpleArt Yes, but I mentioned that, and in this case the presence of such a bound is quite obvious ($-1$ would do the job).

Comment: See your answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537909/fixed-point-iteration-convergence-of-sinx-in-java

Comment: Round-off error effects could lead to $0<x_n=x_{n+1} ,$ depending on your program. For $x>0$ we have  $1-x^2/6<(\sin x)/x<1-x^2/6+x^4/120.$